# How to delete the built-in game Chess Titans on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, gaming

If I delete the files from the directory `C:/Program Files/Microsoft Games/Chess`, they are appeared again over a time. I don't know how, maybe via the Internet

So how to delete the game Chess Titans so that it won't be returned again?

I still use Windows 7

Comment: Does Chess Titans appear in *Control Panel > Programs*? If yes, uninstall it from there.

Comment: No such built-in game (looking at a good Windows 7 machine here). You must have installed it, so then you need the uninstall instructions for it.

Comment: If you don't see "Chess Titans" in Control Panel, then I suggest to install it again and then use [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/) to clean it out completely.

Comment: The built-in games (Chess Titans, FreeCell, Solitaire etc.) as well as built-in programs (Paint, Notepad, Calculator etc.) are installed as a part of Windows during the installation of the very Windows. So they are not listed at "Control Panel > Programs and Features"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have Windows 7 Ultimate, and Chess Titans does exist,

Step 1: Uninstalling the Chess Titans:

```
Go to Start and in the search type "Turn Windows features On or Off".
Select "Turn Windows features On or Off".
Browse to the Games and uncheck the mark in front of "Chess Titans".
Restart the computer.
```

Doing so will not affect CPU or memory usage, and it will be gone.

Hope this helps.

---

This comment makes absolutely no sense whatsoever, unless the one making it is a former Microsoft employee:

"Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers"

---

My solution is concise and to the point and does not require citations or more information.

C'mon guys!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is the easiest, clearest answer I have seen in awhile.  +1.